# d3.extent() gets skipped in d3js execution

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I'm trying to assign a value to my `xDomain` variable below, but when I use the chrome debugger, the value is not defined, and the console does not print the `console.log("DOMAIN" + element.created)` line. What could be causing d3 to look over this line?

```
d3.json("tweets.json", function(error, data){

  if (error) return console.warn(error);

  console.log(data);

  //THIS PART GETS SKIPPED OVER
  var xDomain = d3.extent(data, function(element){
      console.log("DOMAIN" + element.created);
      time = parseTweetTime(element.created);
      return parseTime.parse(time);
  });

  xScale.domain(xDomain);



  var dots = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data.tweet)
      .enter()
      .append("circle");

 dots.attr("r", function(d, i){ 
  return 5;

})
  .attr("cx", function(d){ 
    console.log(d.created);
    date = parseTime.parse(d.created);
    return xScale(date);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d){ return yScale(d.text.length)})
  .style("fill", "black");

});
```

EDIT: 
This is  a sample of the tweets.json file

```
{
   "tweet":[
           {"text": "hello"}
           {"text": "goodbye"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you also provide the tweets.json in the question

Comment: @Cyril I have gone ahead and added that. In other parts of my code where "data" or "d" get passed in as parameters, I don't get any problems.

Comment: Looking at your data the way you calculate your extent is wrong  `d3.extent(data, function(element){` should have been `d3.extent(data.tweet, function(element){` and 1 thing more in your sample there is no `created` but in the extent you are using  it please cross check that

Comment: @Cyril the `data.tweet` did it, please post as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in the way you calculating extent.
As you dataset is like this:

```
{
   "tweet":[
           {"text": "hello"}
           {"text": "goodbye"}
    ]
}
```

So instead of doing this:

```
d3.extent(data, function(element){ ...}
```

Do it this way:

```
d3.extent(data.tweet, function(element){ ... });
```